# Using the rounded data for taking averages

Tags: c, rounding, average

So i have written a code where it reads a file containing a set of data. after that i have rounded up the data to 3 decimal places. later on, i tried to take average of the rounded data within some specific ranges. Ranges are between 0, 0.5 and 0.5 to 1.0 and ... . But the problem is that when i do this, it doesn't use the rounded data and it uses the raw data. How should i change my code so it uses the rounded data? How can i make something that represents the rounded data so i can use it for the rest of my coding?
my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// Data size
#define MAX_ROWS 20
#define MAX_COLUMNS 20
#define LOW_ERROR 0.0
#define HIGH_ERROR 2.5

int main(void) 
{
// Decalred variables
int rowIndex = 0;
int columnIndex = 0;
double rawData[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]; // 2-dimensional array to store our raw data
int decimalPlaces = 3;
float rangeValue[6] = { 0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5 };
int i, num = 0;
float total = 0.0, average;
// Print out the rawdata array
printf(" --- RAW DATA ---\n");
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++) 
{
    // Read up until the last value
    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS; columnIndex++) 
    {
        printf("%.9lf ", rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// Print out the roundup data array
printf(" --- ROUNDED DATA ---\n");
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++)
{
    // Read up until the last value
    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS; columnIndex++)
    {
        if (rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] < LOW_ERROR)
            printf("%.3f ", LOW_ERROR);
        else if (rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] > HIGH_ERROR)
            printf("%.3f ", HIGH_ERROR);
        else
            printf("%.3f ", ceil(rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] * 1000.0) / 1000.0);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//Calculate and store the averages for each range
printf(" --- RANGE TABLE ---\n");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS; columnIndex++)
            if (rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] > rangeValue[i] && rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] <= rangeValue[i + 1])
            {
                total = total + rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex];
                num++;
            }

    }

    average = total / num;
    printf("%f \n", average);
    total = 0;
    average = 0;
    num = 0;
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: I can see where you have code to printf() out the rounded values, but not where you actually round up the values in the array?  Also, you indentation needs attention - I cannot clearly see where main() begins/ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an extra array for holding the rounded data. Something like:

```
double roundedData[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]; 

for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < MAX_ROWS; rowIndex++)
{
    for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < MAX_COLUMNS; columnIndex++)
    {
        roundedData[rowIndex][columnIndex] = ceil(rawData[rowIndex][columnIndex] * 1000.0) / 1000.0);
    }
}
```

After this you can use the variable `roundedData` for calculating the average.